# Excel 2007 Accounting Format

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

In Excel 2007 in my Worksheet, the default accounting format is in Crores whereas I require it in Millions. e.g. `1,25,25,300` is the default one whereas I require `12,525,300`.

Answer (score 2):

To change the default format, you need to change your default model, which is located in: `..\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\Book.XLT`
(source: http://pubs.logicalexpressions.com/Pub0009/LPMArticle.asp?ID=65)

To change the format on your model, <strike>see the link above</strike>, follow these steps:

You need to change the Currency style first:

1. Create a new workbook.
2. On the **Format** menu select **Style**.
3. In the Style Name combo box select **Currency**.
4. Click the **Modify command**.
5. On the Number tab select **Currency**, set the decimal places to 2 (or every change you need to make so that Millions get displayed as you wish), and click OK.
6. In the Style dialog box click **Add**, then Close.

Then you will change the format to your model (so that every new workbook will inherit from this model):

1. Press **Ctrl + A** to select the entire workbook.
2. On the Edit menu select **Clear then All** to clear all data and formats.
3. On the File menu select **Save As**.
4. Change Files of Type at the bottom to **Template** (*.XLT).
5. Name the new template **Book.XLT** (or to the current name depending on you regional settings and the default language of Office)
6. Change Save in to reflect your **XLStart folder** and click Save.

Comment: It would be nice to have the answer here instead of just linking to it!

Comment: @slhck : all right. it's done, i've edited my post.

Comment: Perfect, +1 from me!